# Phug PHP - Variable is printing twice

Tags: php, pug

Creating a wiki based off the mediawiki APIs and ran into some issues.

My code has three variables:

- edit (link to edit)
- title (title of wiki page)
- content (raw HTML of the wiki)

I render these variables on the server has seen here:

```php
$wikipage = $pug->render('views/wiki.pug', array(
        'title' => htmlspecialchars($wiki),
        'content' => $output,
        'edit' => $edit
    ));
echo $wikipage;
```

$output is:

```
<h3> Riverside Rocks API Documentation </h3>
<p>Welcome to the Riverside Rocks API docs!</p>
<p>Base URL: https://riverside.rocks</p>
<p>(HTTPS is required)</p>
<h5> Getting your API key </h5>
<p><a href="https://riverside.rocks/account/login?_ref=wiki" class="external">Sign in to Riverside Rocks</a>. Open your browser's developer tools and run console.log(key);</p>
<p><b>Chat API</b></p>
<p>Endpoint: /v1/new Type: GET</p>
<p>Parameters:</p>
<ul>
<li> key</li>
<li> m (message)</li>
<li> c_id (channel name)</li>
</ul>
<p>Example:</p>
<p>https://example.com/v1/new?m=Hello!&c_id=general&key=12345</p>
```

$title is:

API

$edit is:

https://example.com/index.php?title=API&action=edit

My pug template file prints these variables like so:

```
include head.pug
h1 #{title} - Wiki

#{content}
br
a(href=edit target="_blank") Edit this page
```

Everything works fine, except for the page that the content variable is being printed twice. I did some debugging and found out that this was an issue with Pug as when I printed the variable in my PHP server file, it returned the expected value of being printed once. Any ideas of what I can do to fix this? The package I use to port PugJs to PHP is ["Phug"](https://phug-lang.com/)

Comment: This code chunk is not reproductible from our side as we don't have `$wiki`, `$output` and `$edit`, please provide static values for them allowing to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Good point, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is `#{content}` which is a dynamic tag:

```
- content = 'div'
#{content} Foo
```

(same in Phug or Pug.js)

renders:

```
<div>Foo</div>
```

To insert a variable as raw HTML content, you simply need:

```
!=content
```

Or first a text node:

```
| !{content}
```

Note than you shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` if you already escape in the template: `| #{content}` is escaped, `| !{content}` is displayed raw, `=content` is escaped, `!=content` is raw.